# Lyx only properly works as root in ubuntu

Tags: lyx, ubuntu

I recently updated my ubuntu to 15.04, since then if i open lyx not as root i cannot save files or change documents settings.

Only when i run it with root privileges i can change documents settings and save them, this hasn't been the way before update.

Does anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is the following bug:
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lyx/+bug/1430059

As a workaround, you can run LyX as follows:

```
QT_X11_NO_NATIVE_MENUBAR=1 lyx
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can, but it is quite tricky. When you want to save, just click ALT button and enter **save**, after that your Lyx menu bar will be active again.

[image]